# How can I add MS Graph delegated permissions to a B2C application's API permission

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I need to add `https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read` delegated permission to my B2C application.

When I click on "Add a permission" button and choose Microsoft Graph, the list of "Delegated permissions" is empty as shown below:

[image]

How can I add MS Graph delegated permissions to a B2C application's API permission?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tested in my environment

Azure AD B2C application with supported account type as A**ccounts in any identity provider or organizational directory (for authenticating users with user flows)** only supports only Microsoft Graph **offline_access** and **openid** delegated permissions

If you want to use **User.Read** Microsoft Graph Delegated Permission, you need to create an app registration with supported account type as **Accounts in this organizational directory only (Testing Purpose only - Single tenant)**